# TestNG how to skip test when beforetest fails in inheritance

Tags: java, testing, testng

I have a little problem with testNG. Below my example code:

```
abstract class parent {

 abstract void beforeTest();

 @Test
 void test() {
         // some testing
 }
}

class child extends parent {

 @BeforeTest
 void beforeTest() {
      \\some before things
 }
}
```

And the question is how to do this code work properly? So I want to perform beforeTest() method and if it fails the test method shoud skip. How can I achieve this thing?

Comment: Isn't it work like you want already?

Comment: No because even if beforeTest fails the test method will execute.

Answer (score 0):

Usually, the configuration methods go into the parrent and test classes should extend the parrent.
So, try using this example for your tests:

```
abstract class TestBase {
    @BeforeTest
    public void beforeTest() {
        // do config here 
        // this will run for each of you <test> tag in your testng.xml suite
    }

    @BeforeMethod
    public void beforeMethod() {
        // do some config here 
        // this will run for each method annotated with @Test
    }
}

class SomeTestClass extends TestBase {
    @Test
    public void some_test() {
        // some testing
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, I now that this should be correct solution but project specification required that childs classes implements configuration methods. Thats why I use abstract keyword before beforeTest declaration in parent class.

Comment: you should run the child class in your testng suite. Also, always use @Override annotation when overriding methods (it helps a lot when refactoring code)

Comment: My guess is that you are trying to have multiple configurations for the same test class. You could also achieve that using groups in the BeforeTest annotation. You then call the groups in your testng.xml